# Error with the google map calling direction api from android device

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

I'm using the Google map v2 for android. I would like to call to the directions api to get the points from android device. I registered the Google console key, I can view the map on android. I used this key to include in the directions api call like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false&key=API_KEY
```

The API_KEY is the key I created for maps:

[image: api key for maps and directions]

But when I request from android apps to call to directions api, I got this returned:

```
{
   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.",
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

How can I resolve this error? Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this  is right URL which is call to get direction path between two geo point.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=23%C2%B0%201%27%2050.49711640%22%2C%2072%C2%B0%2034%27%2014.520786762%22&destination=22%C2%B0%2017%27%208.23132830%22%2C%2073%C2%B0%2012%27%2026.766651630%22&sensor=true&mode=driving
```

there is no need to pass `KEY=api-key` in Direction URL..

so,please remove this paramter.and call URL As per above..
api key only put in `<meta-data>` tag in manifest file.

Please call this URL:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false
```

i hope its useful to you.

Comment: Removing the API-KEY from the call is the key. Thanks.

Comment: Won't there be a usage limit for that?

Comment: for today it deprecated

Comment: Now key is required for direction api